# How to calculate the 3rd derivative of this definite integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm having trouble with this problem that envolves derivate of a integral. Take a look please.

> $g(x)$ is a definite function such that $g(1)=6$. Consider the function:
>   $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^2g(t) dt$$
>   Find $f'''(1)$.

I've done this so far:

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}[0.g(x) -x^2.g(0)]$$

$$f''(x)= -x.g(0)$$

$$f'''(x)=-g(0)$$

I'm in a dead end. I supose that I'm wrong because the exercise gave me $g(1)$ that I'm suppose to use.

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you, show us what you have tried.

Comment: sorry, i'm new.

Comment: I would like to inform you that while StackExchange is a Q/A site, [more than just a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^2g(t) dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x^2-2xt+t^2)g(t) dt =$$

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2\int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt-x\int_{0}^{x} tg(t)dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x} t^2g(t)dt$$

Take derivative using product rule and Fundamental Theorem of calculus.

Comment: ok, i'll see where i can go

Comment: Good for you. Do not give up.

Comment: I think I got it. My final answer is f'''(x)=g(x) , so f'''(1)=6.

Comment: Good job. Take care and have fun with math.